# Vuescan V9 x64 Washing color of cream art card to white. How to make it treat the artcard as a image not a document?

Tags: windows-10, scanner, scanning, canon-lide

I am using Hamrick Software Vuescan V9 x64 on Windows 10 with a Canon LIDE 220 Scanner.

I am trying to scan some prints on a light cream colored art card.
The art card has some rather nice texture which I want to keep in the scan as well as the light Cream Colour.

I have tried every combination of settings in Vuescan and no matter what I do Vuescan changes the card (after scanning) to white and loses the texture.

The strange thing is while it is scanning, in the preview window, it sees the art card as I want it to be, light cream with the texture, but as soon as the scan is complete Vuescan changes it to white.

My settings are:

- Input settings
- Media: Colour
- Scan Resolution: 600 dpi
- Filter settings  All Off
- Color settings

I have tried every color balance including:

> none, manual, neutral, auto levels, white balance and so on

Output settings are:

- JPEG file (tick)
- JPEG profile (tick)

Vuescan is well known as one of the best scanner software including for scanning images and photographs and I have used it for years, but this issue is a new one for me.

Comment: Try other software. For example, free IrfanView and many other applications can acquire an image from any TWAIN-compliant scanner. That said, you may need to **manually** adjust *contrast, gamma, brightness and saturation*.  In the question, you have **not** stated if you've done so specifically. See the manual: https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/html/vuesc32.htm

Comment: No I have not played with contrast, gamma, brightness and saturation as frankly I would not know what I am doing.

Comment: Learn the software. You've been pointed to the manual

Comment: [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) as a comment could surely be couched better. Obviously the questioner does not know how to handle _contrast, gamma, brightness and saturation_. I guess that's the reason he asked. Answering that should not be a big problem for someone who is proficient in that area of knowledge. (I ain't!)

Comment: Thank you. If I knew how to use or manipulate contrast, gamma, brightness and saturation then I would have no need to ask the question.